# Why are my characters getting screwed up? (angular gettext's translate filter + $scope.$eval)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using [Angular-Gettext](http://angular-gettext.rocketeer.be/).

Here's my code:

```
var result = $rootScope.$eval('"Description" | translate');
console.log(result);
```

Here's the output to the console:

```
DescripciÃ³n
```

Whereas my `es_VE.po` file has this:

```
msgid "Description"
msgstr "Descripción"
```

Why is it outputting a `Ã³` instead of a `ó`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Sublime for my HTML/Javascript development and I guess Sublime wasn't converting the files to UTF-8.

Opened the `index.html` file in Notepad++ and converted it to UTF-8 and then it worked.

Comment: A note for the future, you can set a character encoding in Sublime Text, so you don't have to open it in a different editor.